# Not understanding JWT "Encryption"

Tags: security, jwt

I have JWT up and running in PHP and Angular Clients.
Everything works perfectly. But I'm still trying to understand something, security-wise, my Angular client doesen't know the key which was used to encrypt the JWT message in the server-side (PHP).
Then, why can it decrypt without it?
Shouldn't the key be important?

Comment: Key is only used to verify JWT's signature, without it you cannot verify issuer's identity (but can assume it's valid and ignore the fact).

Comment: So the key tells the client (angular) , "this answer was provided by me, the PHP client"?

Comment: No, it just skips verifying the issuer and token's integrity altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JWTs can be either signed, encrypted or both. If a token is signed, but not encrypted, everyone can read the contents of the token, but when you don't know the private key, you can't change it. Otherwise, the receiver will notice that the signature won't match anymore.

**additionally**: You can go to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/), paste your token and read the contents. This is jarring for a lot of people initially.

The short answer is that JWT doesn't concern itself with encryption. It cares about validation. That is to say, it can always get the answer for "Have the contents of this token manipulated"? This means user manipulation of the JWT token is futile because the server will know and disregard the token. The server adds a signature based on the payload when issuing a token to the client. Later on it verifies the payload and matching signature.

Please read belove links for more info.

[jwt.io/introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/)

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)

Comment: It is still not clear for me, so, what about my token? I downloaded JWT from GitHub and added to my project, and just plain and simple, defined $token with my message and my $key, and wrote $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);

Comment: Is my token encrypted? How do I know?

Comment: @UrielChami please check my additional answer

Comment: A JWS has 2 dots (`.`) while a JWE has 4